# Get alert when page is scrolled 25 percent only with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show and alert when page is scrolled 25% and 50% respectively.

This is my code it is working fine but not showing an alert.

```
//Get the scroll page percentage
function getHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    )
}

var docheight = getHeight();
function amountScrolled(){
    var winheight= window.innerHeight || (document.documentElement || document.body).clientHeight
    var docheight = getHeight()
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop
    var trackLength = docheight - winheight
    var pageScrolled = Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 100) // gets percentage scrolled (ie: 80 or NaN if tracklength == 0)
    //console.log(pageScrolled + '% scrolled');
    document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = 'Page scroll percentage: ' + pageScrolled + '% scrolled';

    if(pageScrolled === Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 25)) {
      alert('25%');
    }

}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    amountScrolled()
}, false)
```

Can anyone help me with this how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Could be your condition that is never true. You may hop from, in example, 24% to 26%

Comment: Your mathematical calculation `x * 25` is wrong

Comment: so what should it be here?

Comment: `pageScrolled === 25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code

```
if(pageScrolled === Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 25)) {
      alert('25%');
}
```

to

```
if(pageScrolled === 25) {
      alert('25%');
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says:

```
var pageScrolled = ... // gets percentage scrolled (ie: 80 or NaN if tracklength == 0)
```

So `pageScrolled` contains the percent, from 0 to 100. So why are you comparing the percent with `Math.floor(scrollTop/trackLength * 25)` in the if?

Shouldn't it be `pageScrolled === 25`?

Let me refactor your code:

```js
function getTrackLength() {
  const { body, documentElement } = document;
  const winheight = window.innerHeight || (documentElement || body).clientHeight
  const docheight = Math.max(
      body.scrollHeight, documentElement.scrollHeight,
      body.offsetHeight, documentElement.offsetHeight,
      body.clientHeight, documentElement.clientHeight
  );

  return docheight - winheight;
}

function getScrollTop() {
  return window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
}

let previousValue = 0;

function checkScroll() {
  const trackLength = getTrackLength();
  const scrollTop = getScrollTop();
  const percent = Math.floor(scrollTop / trackLength * 100) 

  console.log({ percent, previousValue });

  if (percent >= 25 && previousValue < 25) {
    console.log('Just passed 25%');
  } else if (percent >= 50 && previousValue < 50) {
    console.log('Just passed 50%');
  }

  previousValue = percent;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll, false);
```

This new snippet will trigger even if the scroll passes from 24% to 26%, since it's storing the last scroll position and comparing it with the current one.